# Filter a laravel collection in blade template

Tags: collections, filter, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I filter my laravel object in a blade template as it follows

```
 @php($dm = $demands->where('week', $w)->where('projectid', $project->id))
```

and I want to have for example `{{ $dm->time }}` if exists

and I want to output values inside of this object by key in a table, the key depending on query can exist or not, how do I suppress error in this case if key do not exists

Answer (score 0):

Use Either of the two:

1. `isset($variable)`

or

2. `empty($variable)`

> $variable is your key. isset() helps you to check if variable is
>   present and empty() helps you to check if it is present and not null.

Hope this helps you. Let me know if any Question.